# for loop to echo the sequential command lines?

Tags: linux, for-loop

how to use for loop in linux to generate the following lines?

```
zcat ~/tools/sample66621D.fastq | bowtie2 -a - | samtools ->sample66621D.BAM
zcat ~/tools/sample66622D.fastq | bowtie2 -a - | samtools ->sample66622D.BAM
zcat ~/tools/sample66623D.fastq | bowtie2 -a - | samtools ->sample66623D.BAM
```

I've tried:

```
for ((a=21;a<=23;a++))
  echo "zcat ~/tools/sample666$aD.fastq | bowtie2 -a - | samtools ->sample666$aD.BAM"
done
```

but it turned to be three identical lines .

```
zcat ~/tools/sample666.fastq | bowtie2 -a - | samtools ->sample666.BAM
zcat ~/tools/sample666.fastq | bowtie2 -a - | samtools ->sample666.BAM
zcat ~/tools/sample666.fastq | bowtie2 -a - | samtools ->sample666.BAM
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

`$aD` is a valid variable name. You must delimit the variable name with brackets, i.e. `${a}`.

Comment: Thanks, it works. what about outputting these echo command lines to a run.sh file? The -> did not work here.